# How to know which RAM slots are in use in a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, macbook-pro

I'd like to upgrade the memory of a 15" Macbook Pro. It came with 4GB out of the box, but I don't know if it came as 1x4GB or 2x2GB.

Is there a way to know that, before unscrewing the computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the *Apple* menu, select *About This Mac*. Then click on *More Info…* and select the *Memory* tab.

[image: About this Mac dialog]

Answer (score 2):

It will most likely be 2 slots. [Double check](http://support.apple.com/specs/#macbookpro) your specs depending on model year. Most, if not all, are coming with 2x2GB

```
 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1333MHz DDR3 memory;
 two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB
```

Edit - looks like all recent 15" have 2 slots. I just upgraded my early 2011 and it had two, make sure you [read the directions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1651) before you upgrade. You'll need a #00 head screwdriver to get the bottom off, if you have a recent model macbook.

Comment: You were right, 2x2GB. I wanted to be sure however, Oliver's suggestion confirmed it.